# Manually adding Libraries on react-native ^60

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

Unsure where else to address this.

The autolinker feature is great, however, i've come across issues with adding libraries manually after rn ^60.

A good example would be the `PushNotificationIOS` library. In the past all that needed to be done was manually add it in the `Libraries` and tweak Build Phases a little.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking

Doing the same process now won't build as the build system cant find the header paths.
**So the question is:**

**Is it the case that manually linking cant work like it used to anymore?**

**P.S:** Another approach would have been to use the @react-native-community versionf of PushNotificationIOS but that seems to be problematic right now because of : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

Here's my upgrade path for 0.60.x with react-native-push-notification, worked after resolving several errors:

1. Upgrade to latest: `yarn add react-native-push-notification`
2. `yarn add @react-native-community/push-notification-ios`
3. Ensure any references are removed from your Podfile (including commented references, or react-native will still complain)
4. in Xcode, remove RNCPushNotification from General -> Linked Frameworks
5. Remove previous PushNotification code from AppDelegate.m
6. `react-native link @react-native-community/push-notification-ios`
7. If this didn't add code in AppDelegate.m (it didn't in my case) then manually add the code from [their GitHub page](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios)

One more gotcha - when testing that it works, make sure your app is closed or a local notification won't fire.

The process above resolved all my errors.  Hope it works for you!

Comment: There's one more step, delete the line in your Podfile that was created from manual linking.

Delete this:
pod 'RNCPushNotificationIOS', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios'